# not-null property references a null or transient value in one to one with primary key as join column

Tags: hibernate, jpa

Can someone help me here, why I'm getting below exception. I have checked various similar links, but no one is matching this use case.
I'm trying to create relation between User table and Address table via Primary key as join column in User table.

Hibernate Version - 5.2.18

```
Hibernate: create table User (userId numeric(19,0) not null, primary key (userId))
Hibernate: select next_val as id_val from hibernate_sequence with (updlock, rowlock)
Hibernate: update hibernate_sequence set next_val= ? where next_val=?
Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.PropertyValueException: not-null property references a null or transient value : com.vikas.projects.hibernate.tests.oneTone.User.shippingAddress
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
```

Users.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.PrimaryKeyJoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="USERS")
public class User {
    
    @Id
    private Long id;
    
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String firstName;
    
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String lastName;
    
    @OneToOne(
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY,
            optional=false
            )
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private Address shippingAddress;
    
    public User() {
        
    }
    
    public User(Long id, String fName, String lName) {
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = fName;
        this.lastName = lName;
    }

}
```

Address.java

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Address {
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column (nullable=false)
    private String city;
    @Column (nullable = false)
    private String street;
    
    public Address() {
        
    }
    
    public Address (String city, String street) {
        this.city = city;
        this.street = street;
    }
    
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    
    public void setCity(String city) {
        this.city = city;
    }
    
    public void setStreet(String street) {
        this.street=street;
    }

}
```

ApplicationTest.java

```
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;

import com.vikas.projects.hibernate.tests.DbOperations;

public class ApplicationTest {
    
    public static void main( String[] args) {
        Address shippingAddress = new Address("CityNameLiteral", "StreetNameLiteral");
        Session session = DbOperations.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.persist(shippingAddress);
        Long shippingAddressId = shippingAddress.getId();
        User userObj = new User(shippingAddressId, "firstNameLiteral", "lastNameLiteral");
        session.persist(userObj);
        tx.commit();
        session.close();
        
    }

}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your User constructor looks like this:

```
public User(Long id, String fName, String lName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
}
```

and you are using it like this:

```
User userObj = new User(shippingAddressId, "firstNameLiteral", "lastNameLiteral");
```

this means you are setting the user objects id to the shipping address id but you aren't actually setting the shipping address object in the user to anything.

The following steps should solve your issue:

```
public class User {
    // Add @GeneratedValue to your User#id (I think you don't need to set the strategy 
    // here, but not 100% sure)
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    // ...
}
```

```
// Change User constructor like this
public User(Address shippingAddress, String fName, String lName) {
    this.shippingAddress = shippingAddress;
    this.firstName = fName;
    this.lastName = lName;
}
```

```
public static void main( String[] args) {
    Address shippingAddress = new Address("CityNameLiteral", "StreetNameLiteral");
    Session session = DbOperations.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.persist(shippingAddress);
    // Use the Adress object now
    User userObj = new User(shippingAdress, "firstNameLiteral", "lastNameLiteral");
    session.persist(userObj);
    tx.commit();
    session.close();
}
```

If you are unsure I would recommend you to follow this example, although it offers a 2 table solution: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for your help here. But I'm really sorry that your solution is giving me "IdentifierGenerationException". However, also like to thanks you as reason that you have provided here, is correct. I was not assigning shippingAddress to user and this is why it was not working. So I have assigned it via setter and its working now.

Comment: @vikasyadav53 you might need to specify a generation strategy for the id then